# Multiple Regression Assumption

Tags: regression, linear-regression

If I am running a multiple linear regression model with six independent variables against dependent variable,
do the assumptions of multiple regression need to be satisfied?

or does this only applies if we are using the least squares method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the assumptions should be satisfied in either of the cases. Typically it can be difficult to fulfill all the assumptions but the more assumptions are satisfied the more reliable the results become.

Here is a helpful link regarding the same: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/multiple-regression-using-spss-statistics.php

Comment: I was told by my teacher that the assumptions do not need to be satisfied as all we are interested in is running a regression to explain the mean of the dependent based on the independent.

Comment: Hi @roronoa Ideally they should be satisfied if you want reliable results. If you don't fulfill the conditions you will still get a result and some insight but then the reliability of output is under question. Anyway I will try to research more about it. Thanks :)